# PHP count() always return 1

Tags: php, json, loops, foreach

I have a JSON object that im trying to iterate to count how many value there are inside the object.

My JSON;

```
[{
    "accountId": "1746756959",
    "containerId": "7454209",
    "containerVersionId": "7",
    "container": {
        "accountId": "1746756959",
        "containerId": "7454209"
    },
    "tag": [{
        "accountId": "1746756959",
        "name": "Universal Analytics",
        "parameter": [{
            "key": "overrideGaSettings",
            "type": "boolean",
            "value": "false"
        }]
    }, {
        "accountId": "1746756959",
        "parameter": [{
            "key": "detectTitle",
            "type": "boolean",
            "value": "true"
        }]
    }, {
        "accountId": "1746756959",
        "name": "contentEngagement",
        "parameter": [{
            "key": "html",
            "type": "template",
            "value": "<script>\n\n<\/script>"
        }]
    }],
    "trigger": [{
        "accountId": "1746756959",
        "name": "Trigger 1",
        "workspaceId": null
    }, {
        "accountId": "1746756959",
        "name": "Trigger 2",
        "workspaceId": null
    }, {
        "accountId": "1746756959",
        "containerId": "7454209",
        "fingerprint": "1507893475158",
        "name": "Trigger 3",
        "notes": null,
        "parentFolderId": null,
        "path": null,
        "tagManagerUrl": null,
        "triggerId": "13",
        "type": "windowLoaded",
        "workspaceId": null
    }],
    "variable": [{
        "accountId": "1746756959",
        "containerId": "7454209",
        "disablingTriggerId": null,
        "enablingTriggerId": null,
        "fingerprint": "1505216399119",
        "name": "Google Analytics Settings",
        "notes": null,
        "parentFolderId": null,
        "path": null,
        "scheduleEndMs": null,
        "scheduleStartMs": null,
        "tagManagerUrl": null,
        "type": "gas",
        "variableId": "1",
        "workspaceId": null,
        "parameter": [{
            "key": "cookieDomain",
            "type": "template",
            "value": "auto"
        }]

    }]
}]
```

When i try to iterate and print out the values i can do it, but when i count it i get result like `(1 1 1)` when there should be `(3)`. I suspect it has something to do with the foreach. My PHP code looks like this:

```
   foreach($LiveContainer as $item) {
            foreach ($item['tag'] as $accountPath) {
                echo count($accountPath->name); echo "<br>";
            }}
```

Result:

> 1 1 1

What i want is to count how many items there are in `tag`.

**PS:** I removed alot from JSON since its very long, maby "name" is not available in all tags, sorry for that

Thanks

Comment: What's wrong with `count($item['tag'])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach($LiveContainer as $item) {
    echo count($item['tag']); echo "<br>";
}
```

Comment: Stupid stupid stupid of me, i forgot to echo it thats why it did not work the first time so i made two foreach. Sorry for wasting your time and thanks alot

Comment: Admin you can delete this post. Just waste of space on server :P

Comment: @Asim you can delete by yourself, look at the delete link at the end of your question (along with share, edit...)

Comment: Not possible. Says that persons have already used much time here thats why i cannot delete it